# No mapping found for field 'questionId' on class 'project\JuristsBundle\Entity\Answers'

Tags: php, symfony

Уже гуглил и пробовал делать уже полностью из офф документации и с примеров, который находил на аналогичные вопросы - не работает.

**Entity\Questions.php**

```
/**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $answersId;

/**
     * Get answers
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAnswers()
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

    /**
     * Set answersId
     *
     * @param integer $answersId
     *
     * @return AnswersId
     */
    public function setAnswersId($answersId)
    {
        $this->answersId = $answersId;

        return $this;
    }
```

**Entity\Answers.php**

```
/**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $question_id;

/**
     * Set question_id
     *
     * @param integer $question_id
     *
     * @return Answers
     */

    public function setQuestions_id($question_id)
    {
        $this->question_id = $question_id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question_id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getQuestion_id()
    {
        return $this->question_id;
    }
```

**Resources\config\doctrine\Questions.orm.yml**

```
fields:
        question_id:
            type: integer
oneToOne:
    answersId:
        targetEntity: Answers
        mappedBy: questionId
```

**Resources\config\doctrine\Answers.orm.yml**

```
oneToOne:
        questionId:
            targetEntity: Questions
            inversedBy: answers
            joinColumn:
                name: question_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Answer (score 1):

Измените название поля **questionId**, так что бы оно у вас везде одинаковым было, а не так как у вас сейчас в одном месте **question_id**, в другом **questionId**.